# Spring mvc page validation not working for checkbox. works for text fields

Tags: spring-mvc

In Spring MVC 3.0, there is a class `org.springframework.validation.BindingResult` which finds the form parameters.
There is a method `result.rejectValue("fieldName","errorMessage");`
This method will attach an error message to a field that fails a validation. (e.g. if a phone number field contains alphabets, it will put the error message on top of the field.

The thing is when the field is not a text field but a checkbox, the message does not appear.

So if the user has clicked checkbox #1 but not clicked dependent checkbox #2, I wish to show the error on top of the checkbox#2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case I suggest bind validation error to a whole form (instead of to a particular field):

```
result.rejectValue("errorMessage");
```

And show this global errors before other fields:

```
<form:form>
    <form:errors />

    // form fields
</form:form>
```